# c-casting to type against c-casting to type's reference

Tags: c++, casting, enums

In c++, what is the difference in c-casting to the type or to the reference of the type ?

```
foo = (unsigned int) whatever;  

// Is this the same as: 
foo = (unsigned int&) whatever;
```

Comment: These are different questions, both of which I'm sure have been asked and answered many times before. Good way to avoid "duplicate" close-votes, though. Would you please file one question per question?

Comment: 2 is not static casting. It's C-style casting. Use `static_cast` instead.

Comment: There are no guarantees (in C++) that all enums will fit in an unsigned int. In your example though, it will.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit edited static cast to c-cast, you are right!

Comment: @sixlettervariables question edited accordingly

Comment: IS the second code even valid?

Comment: @paul23: Short answer? [Yes](http://codepad.org/t5gZ660k). Long answer? What happened when you loaded up your compiler and gave it a try?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is not even remotely the same.

(In some cases the exact nature of the cast depends of what `whatever` is. I will assume that the type of `whatever` is unrelated to `unsigned int`.)

C-casting to reference type `unsigned int &` is equivalent to performing a `reinterpret_cast` to that type

```
foo = reinterpret_cast<unsigned int &>(whatever);
```

which is by definition equivalent to

```
foo = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&whatever);
```

`whatever` is required to be a lvalue in this case.

In other words, casting to reference is just another method of *type punning*. You are simple *reinterpreting* the memory occupied by `whatever` as an `unsigned int` object. In general case the behavior is undefined. For example, if `sizeof whatever` is smaller than size of `unsigned int`, the reinterpretation will also involve some "wild" memory that does not even belong to `whatever`.

Meanwhile a non-reference C-cast is just a value *conversion*, not memory reinterpretation. For arithmetic conversions to `unsigned int` it is equivalent to `static_cast` (but if `whatever` is a pointer, it is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast`). It reads the *value* of `whatever` and converts it to `unsigned int` type according to the language conversion rules (if the conversion exists).

For example, this

```
float f = 5;
unsigned int i = (unsigned int) f;
```

will convert the *value* of `f` to type `unsigned int`, which means that `i` will receive value `5`. At the same time, if on your platform sizes `unsigned int` and `float` have the same size, then this

```
unsigned int i = (unsigned int &) f;
```

will actually reinterpret internal object representation of `float` object `f` with value `5` as an object of type `unsigned int`. The resultant value of `i` is generally unpredictable. Typically it won't be even close to `5` (in popular implementations you will simply receive the IEE754 representation of the original `float` value in `i`).

Comment: Nitpick, casting to a reference could also be a static cast if there is an inheritance relationship between the source and target types. This is actually important in some scenarios with multiple inheritance, as the `reinterpret_cast` will provide a pointer to the start of the source object, but `static_cast` will correct the pointer to refer to the start of the target object. (+1 anyways as the question is about `unsigned int`)

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas: Yes, thanks. To avoid overloading the answer with details, I assumed that we are talking specifically about casting to `unsigned int`.

Comment: reinterpret_cat iz in ur ceiling, watching u convert ur vrblz

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: Got it :) Fixed. Thanks. Meow.

Comment: reinterpret_cat waz in ur answr, constitutin typoz